# Realm Android: get item count during migration

Tags: android, realm

I am using Realm on Android.

During a version migration, is there a way to get the item count of one of the tables?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

They dynamic realm that is provided during the migration has the full query capabilities of a standard Realm, so the following should work

```
public void migrate(DynamicRealm realm, long oldVersion, long newVersion) {
  long count = realm.where("MyClass").count();
}
```

You can read more about dynamic Realms here: https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/#dynamic-realms

Comment: Great, thanks, that cleared things up. You might want to add a link to "dynamic realm" in the migration documentation and state that you cannot use the standard Realm during a migration.

Comment: Thanks. Will do that.

Comment: @ChristianMelchior , hi please check this about realm migration https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59855380/how-can-i-replace-a-listobjects-with-object-field-in-realm