# Transform an object to a list[object] in Realm as migration ( How can i replace a list[objects] with object field in Realm? )

Tags: java, android, kotlin, realm, realm-migration

I want to import existing `token` into `tokenList` as first item , for example if someone has a
 `token="abc"` after `migration` , i want he/she has `tokenList` that `tokenList[0]=="abc"`

**This is my migration code:**

```
public class RealmMigration implements io.realm.RealmMigration {
.
.
.
    if (oldVersion == 3) {
        final RealmObjectSchema bankSchema = realmSchema.get("Bank");
        final RealmObjectSchema tokenSchema = realmSchema.get("Token");
        DynamicRealmObject bank = realm.createObject("Bank",1);
        Token token = bank.get("Token");
        bankSchema.addRealmListField("tokenList", tokenSchema);
        List<Token> tokenList = bank.get("tokenList");
        if (token != null) tokenList.add(token);
        bankSchema.removeField("Token");
    }
}
```

I replace this in new version :

```
@RealmField(name = "tokenList")
private RealmList<Token> mTokenList;
```

With this in old version in my class :

```
@RealmField(name = "Token")
private Token mToken;
```

Comment: So what doesn't work? Is there an exception, etc? Did you update the schema version number to trigger the migration?

Comment: Yes i update it , migration is well but app crash when i install new version on old version because i cant insert existing token(old field in Bank) into tokenList(new field in Bank) .java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0 because bankList not filled in migration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created new **[issue](https://github.com/realm/realm-java/issues/6725)** in **Realm GitHub** then i found right way for **transform** `object` to `list[object]` in **Realm** and `insert` existing object from previous version to new version of application.

In this example we want to `transform` `Token` **object** to `tokenList[Token]` in `Bank` model.

In last version of migration put this :

```
public class RealmMigration implements io.realm.RealmMigration {

.

.

.

        if (oldVersion == 3) {
            //Create a schema for Bank
            final RealmObjectSchema bankSchema = realmSchema.get("Bank");
            //Create a schema for Token that has been in Bank model
            final RealmObjectSchema tokenSchema = realmSchema.get("Token");
            //We use bankSchema for add tokenList field and transform
            bankSchema
                .addRealmListField("tokenList", tokenSchema)
                .transform((obj) -> {//obj is bank model,we have a transform in bank model
                         DynamicRealmObject token = obj.get("Token");
                         List<DynamicRealmObject> tokenList = obj.get("tokenList");
                                //We add token from pre version to tokenList in new version
                                if (token != null) tokenList.add(token);
                            }
                    )
                    //Finally remove unwanted field
                    .removeField("Token");
        }
}
```